# What are the consequences of adding Pooling=True with Integrated Security?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My application is on ASP.NET 4 with SQL Server 2008 R2 backend.

Connection string is using Integrated Security. I want to know what are the advantages of adding:

**pooling = true;
max pool size =** *N*

in the connection string when Integrated Security is set to true.

Shall I enable it or not?

**Edited**

Is the problem discussed in this question possible when pooling is not enabled?

[Application starts displaying wrong data but corrects when SQL Server service restarts.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1772286.aspx/1?Application%20starts%20displaying%20wrong%20data%20but%20corrects%20when%20SQL%20Server%20service%20restarts%20)

**Edited:**

The Web.Config file contains following lines:

```
<add name="ConStringPWS" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pWS;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<identity impersonate="true" userName="Server\Administrator" password="xyz"/>
```

Comment: I don't think connection pooling relates to the issue raised on the other forum - it sounds more like an inappropriate use of global/static/shared objects - since it sounds more like the wrong result sets are being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, i think we should enable the connection pool.
(Actually, by default the pooling is enabled and max pool size is 100)

As far as i know, The pooling is not related to Integrated Security configuration.

Pooling connections will help your application on better performance and better scalability area. Pooling is a technique to reduce the cost of repeatedly opening and closing connections(Physical).

As far as i know to answer your question, How to check Pooling is enable or not.
I think someone here can give you a better answer.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cnnBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(yourConnection.ConnectionString);
bool isPooling = cnnBuilder.Pooling;
```

Comment: Is there a way to check whether pooling is enabled or not?

Comment: I update my comment above. I hope this will help. I am not sure this way is best way to check pooling.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling):

> Only connections with the same configuration can be pooled. ADO.NET keeps several pools at the same time, one for each configuration. Connections are separated into pools by connection string, and by Windows identity when integrated security is used. Connections are also pooled based on whether they are enlisted in a transaction.
> Since in the integrated security mode you will be accessing the database under the identity of your AppPool/worker Process (unless you are using impersonation), it is extremely important to **use** the connection pooling as essentially ALL requests to your site will be using connections with the same configuration. Not pooling them will have a serious impact on your application performance.

Comment: Updated my post above. Please see the link.

Answer (score 1):

The key pooling problem is if integrated security is on, *and* impersonation is used - is your site like that?

In such a case, pooling is unlikely to be useful, since each independent user will end up with a separate pool.

See [Impersonation/Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649265.aspx):

> Be aware that impersonation prevents the efficient use of connection pooling if you access downstream databases by using the impersonated identity.

Comment: Please see my updated post. I am using both, Integrated Security and Impersonate. Please also see the link where I have discussed the problem.